# How to get lookback moving average of a timeseries with window based on date in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series, moving-average

I have a timeseries like this:

```
                  times | data
1994-07-25 15:15:00.000 | 165
1994-07-25 16:00:00.000 | 165
1994-07-26 18:45:00.000 | 165

1994-07-27 15:15:00.000 | 165
1994-07-27 16:00:00.000 | 165

1994-07-28 18:45:00.000 | 165
1994-07-28 19:15:00.000 | 63
1994-07-28 20:35:00.000 | 64
1994-07-28 21:55:00.000 | 64

1994-07-29 14:15:00.000 | 62

1994-07-30 15:35:00.000 | 62
1994-07-30 16:55:00.000 | 61
```

I would like to do a **lookback** moving average on this data, but with a window based **on date**, **not on rows or datetime**.

---

For example, say `lookback = 3 days`, then for

```
1994-07-29 14:15:00.000 | 62
```

its lookback moving average value should be the average of

```
1994-07-26 18:45:00.000 | 165

1994-07-27 15:15:00.000 | 165
1994-07-27 16:00:00.000 | 165

1994-07-28 18:45:00.000 | 165
1994-07-28 19:15:00.000 | 63
1994-07-28 20:35:00.000 | 64
1994-07-28 21:55:00.000 | 64
```

Because it is a 3 days lookback, so the average will will starts from `1994-07-26` for 3 days, no matter how many rows within one day.

---

In addition, for multiple rows with the same date (not including time), their lookback moving average values should be the same.

---

How can I easily achieve that?

Comment: `numpy` arrays are able to deal with a `datetime` format, see the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html). Then you can do arithmetics on the timestamps according to your needs to define a filter criterion!

Answer (score 5):

I would use the pandas [DatetimeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) to accumulate the values for each date.

You can then use [rolling_mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html) to calculate the average you require.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'times': np.array(['1994-07-25 15:15:00.000',
                                '1994-07-25 16:00:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-26 18:45:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-27 15:15:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-27 16:00:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-28 18:45:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-28 19:15:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-28 20:35:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-28 21:55:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-29 14:15:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-30 15:35:00.000', 
                                '1994-07-30 16:55:00.000'], dtype='datetime64'),
                       'data': [165,165,165,165,165,165,63,64,64,62,62,61]})
df = df.set_index('times')
g = df.groupby(df.index.date)
days = 3
pandas.rolling_mean(g.sum(), days)
```

This gives:

```
1994-07-25         NaN
1994-07-26         NaN
1994-07-27  275.000000
1994-07-28  283.666667
1994-07-29  249.333333
1994-07-30  180.333333
```

You might wish to play with the `center` and `min_periods` arguments on `rolling_mean` to get the exact results you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), specifically the [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd
```

First, read in your data, assuming saved as csv:

```
df=pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',sep=' | ',parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
```

Then resample over day-long periods, note this defaults to 'mean' of the samples in each day:

```
df2 = df.resample('D')
```

To get last 3 days:

```
df2[-3:]
```

gives:

```
            data
1994-07-28  89.0
1994-07-29  62.0
1994-07-30  61.5
```

assuming `yourfile.txt` is saved like this:

```
times | data
1994-07-25 15:15:00.000 | 165
1994-07-25 16:00:00.000 | 165
1994-07-26 18:45:00.000 | 16
1994-07-27 15:15:00.000 | 165
1994-07-27 16:00:00.000 | 165
1994-07-28 18:45:00.000 | 165
1994-07-28 19:15:00.000 | 63
1994-07-28 20:35:00.000 | 64
1994-07-28 21:55:00.000 | 64
1994-07-29 14:15:00.000 | 62
1994-07-30 15:35:00.000 | 62
1994-07-30 16:55:00.000 | 61
```